# Java objects to JSON without key

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm getting to know json better. But I have some problems with that. I want to create JSON objects from Java classes.
I'm trying Java-objects convert to JSON with jackson.

What I want is that:

```
{
    "id" : "005be2f0",
    "attachments":
    [
        {"id":"Y98-8370"},  
        {"id":"Y98-8371"},  
        {"id":"Y98-8372"},  

        {"filename" : "DummyDoc", "filetype" : "pdf"}
    ]
}
```

But what I got with the following classes is that:

```
{
  "id" : "005be2f0",
  "attachments" : [ {
    "id" : 
    [ 
        {"id":"Y98-8370"},  
        {"id":"Y98-8371"},  
        {"id":"Y98-8372"},  
    ],
    "filename" : "DummyDoc",
    "filetype" : "pdf"
  } ]
}
```

And this are my classes:

```
public class Attachment {
    @JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "filename", "filetype" })
    public class Attachment {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private List<AttachmentID> id = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonProperty("filename")
    private String filename;

    @JsonProperty("filetype")
    private String filetype;

    public List<AttachmentID> getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(List<AttachmentID> id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getFiletype() {
        return filetype;
    }

    public void setFiletype(String filetype) {
        this.filetype = filetype;
    }
}
```

I need this class for ID of the attachment.

```
public class AttachmentID {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    public AttachmentID(String attachmentID) {
        this.id = attachmentID;
    }

    public AttachmentID() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String getAttachmentID() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setAttachmentID(String attachmentID) {
        this.id = attachmentID;
    }
}
```

And my RecordAttachment class.

```
    @JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "attachments" })
public class RecordAttachment {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("attachments")
    private List<Attachment> attachments = null;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("attachments")
    public List<Attachment> getAttachments() {
        return attachments;
    }

    @JsonProperty("attachments")
    public void setAttachments(List<Attachment> attachments) {
        this.attachments = attachments;
    }
}
```

is that possible? 
Does this have to do with JsonNode, ObjectNode etc.?
I would be very happy if someone could help me.

I mean with key the IDs in array.

Comment: is the @JsonProperty("id") over the List<AttachmentId> id property necessary?

Comment: no, just for readability.

Comment: Jackson annotations do not work like comments, you need to be careful to only give your properties the annotations they need

Comment: If you want to serialize a JSON that way, you should design your classes accordingly.  What you want is an Attachment as an empty superclass/interface for FileAttachment, containing filename and fileType, and IdAttachment, containing an ID.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not quite understand. Could you explain a little more in detail? Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 : Custom serializer**

Details : You can tell jackson how to serialize your object. If you want to serialize it always in the same way, you can specify at the class level that it should always use this serializer. If you believe you will need other serializers, you should customize your objectMapper instead:
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

```
 SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
 module.addSerializer(Attachment.class, new AttachmentSerializer());
```

The attachment serializer:

```
public class AttachmentSerializer extends StdSerializer<Attachment> {

    public AttachmentSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public AttachmentSerializer(Class<Attachment> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
            Attachment attachment, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeArrayFieldStart("attachments");
        for (AttachmentID attachmentID : attachment.getId()) {
            jgen.writeStartObject();
            jgen.writeStringField("id", attachmentID.getAttachmentID());
            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("filename", attachment.getFilename());
        jgen.writeStringField("filetype", attachment.getFiletype());

        jgen.writeEndObject();
        jgen.writeEndArray();
        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

and add :

```
@JsonSerialize(using = AttachmentSerializer.class)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "filename", "filetype"})
public class Attachment {
```

I've added custom serializer just on your Attachment class because it is the only one that needs special handling.

**Solution 2: create a custom RecordAttachmentDTO with the target fields needed and serialize it instead of RecordAttachment.**

```
public class RecordAttachmentDTO {
    private String id;
    private List<Map<String, String>> attachments = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecordAttachmentDTO(RecordAttachment recordAttachment) {
        this.id = recordAttachment.getId();
        List<Attachment> attachments = recordAttachment.getAttachments();
        attachments.forEach(attachment -> addAttachment(attachment));

    }

    private void addAttachment(Attachment attachment) {
        attachment.getId().forEach(attachmentID -> attachments.add(Collections.singletonMap("id", attachmentID.getAttachmentID())));
        Map<String, String> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
        fileMap.put("filename", attachment.getFilename());
        fileMap.put("fileType", attachment.getFiletype());
        attachments.add(fileMap);
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getAttachments() {
        return attachments;
    }

    public void setAttachments(List<Map<String, String>> attachments) {
        this.attachments = attachments;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

This solution will help you have multiple serializers if needed. This solution is basically a wrapper of your original object. Instead of serializing the original object, you are serializing a wrapper instead.

**Solution 3: build JsonNode objects**

```
public static String serializeRecordAttachment(RecordAttachment recordAttachment) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode recordNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
    recordNode.put("id", recordAttachment.getId());
    List<Attachment> attachments = recordAttachment.getAttachments();
    recordNode.set("attachments", 
    createAttachmentNode(objectMapper,attachments));
    return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(recordNode.toString);
}

private static ArrayNode createAttachmentNode(ObjectMapper objectMapper, List<Attachment> attachments) {
    ArrayNode attachmentsNode = objectMapper.createArrayNode();
    attachments.forEach(attachment -> addAttachment(objectMapper, attachmentsNode, attachment);
    return attachmentsNode;
}

private static void addAttachment(ObjectMapper objectMapper, ArrayNode attachmentsNode, Attachment attachment) {
    attachment.getId().forEach(idField -> {
        ObjectNode attchIdNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
        attchIdNode.put("id", idField.getAttachmentID());
        attachmentsNode.add(attchIdNode);
    });
    ObjectNode fileNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
    fileNode.put("filename", attachment.getFilename());
    fileNode.put("filetype", attachment.getFiletype());
    attachmentsNode.add(fileNode);
}
```

This solution is similar with Solution 2, the advantage is that you don't need a wrapper object.